# How to get an element and all its contained elements into one collection?

Tags: jquery

I am learning the ways to get a collection together. Is there a way to make the following selection simpler? It's not a real world example, I'm just trying to understand. I' have this `ul` and want to get the first `li` with all its following content.

```
<ul class="foo">
    <li>
        <div><p></p><div>
        <div><a></a><div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div>content<div>
        <div>content<div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried this, but then I am missing the children of the divs.

```
$('.foo li:first').children().addBack()
```

What's the easiest and most performant way to get all of them? Thanks

Comment: `$('.foo li:first').children().addBack()` is equivalent to just `$('.foo li:first')` and is therefore pretty redundant.

Comment: So we are clear. You just want the first 'li' and all of its children, right?

Comment: You may want to check  .. [JqueryContents](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) ... and ... [JqueryFind](https://api.jquery.com/find/) ... and ... [JqueryChildren](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `"*"` selector for this

```
$('.foo li:first').find("*")
```

But remember it the slowest selector, hence always try to avoid using it

For more details [check it out](https://api.jquery.com/all-selector/)

Comment: The OP included the `addBack()` method, which this omits, hence the `li` itself will not be selected. Also, using the `*` is pointless in this case. Selecting just `$('.foo li:first')` will get you the exact same result set, and faster too.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan but i need the li including all its content, the two divs and there content as well.

Comment: Which is exactly what `$('.foo li:first')` gives you. If you select the `li` it will contain all the `div` and other child/grandchild elements with it.

Comment: The point is what you need to do with those elements @Gregor ... read the html? the contents ? change css?

Comment: I guess OP wants to select all the element inside first *li*, please let me know if I am wrong.